# SQL All Procs have WITH RECOMPLILE so how to maintain a bloated plan cache

Tags: execution-plan, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, plan-cache, star-schema

I'm working a star schema data warehouse created in Azure SQL database where the last developer included `WITH RECOMPILE` on all the Procs.

This I believe was because the ETL only executes these Procs twice a day so the overhead of recompiles is minimal.

However, isn't there a risk of the cache becoming bloated with all those plans and if so, what's the best way to maintain the plan cache to keep it trim and as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plans generated for queries with forced recompile are not cached.  See [RECOMPILE Hints and Execution Plan Caching](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/) for details.

Comment: If it's helpful, the article [Recompile Meditation: Is a plan always cached?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/recompile-meditation-is-a-plan-always-cached/ba-p/333993) by Joseph Pilov also mentions that `RECOMPILE` hints result in a plan that isn't cached either.